# Facebook: Share unique image with common URL and discard the image locally. Is it kept on FB?

Tags: facebook, facebook-share

The problem:

I want to share a unique image each time a url is shared on Facebook. This to let users of my site share emotions and their score from having played the game they just played on the site.

So, they would share the game url, which is the same to all, but associate it with their results and an emoticon or something like that, all baked into an image created on the fly, saved on my server.

I **do not** want to have to keep those images after they have been shared as storage becomes cluttered.

Is this possible?

AFAIK, sharing a unique image for a url that has been shared many times before can easily be achieved via sending in the img url explicitly to the share.php along with the url to share. Is this a correct assumption?

So the question, as it stands:

Is it possible to share a unique image to the same URL over and over, and then throw away the image but it stays visible with the link on Facebook?

Comment: _“can easily be achieved via sending in the img url explicitly to the share.php along with the url to share. Is this a correct assumption?”_ - no, it is not; not any more. As part of the fight against fake news (people posting articles from reputable sources, but with completely misleading title/description/thumbnail), this has been limited to posts made by pages, and the page must have claimed “ownership” of the domain before.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So, maybe an alternative strategy is needed. I wonder how people go about this kind of sharing i.e. I've used a service, and I want to "brag" about how well I did by sharing a picture autogenerated by that service. Thanks anyways for clearing this up.

Comment: Pretty much the only way is to provide unique URLs for each “brag”, that then each specify their own thumbnail image. The disadvantage is that Facebook will see them as individual Open Graph objects, meaning likes and shares will also be counted for each one on their own.

Comment: As for “storing” the images, you don’t necessarily have to, if you have a script that can create them on-the-fly. Pass the necessary data you need via the image URL (plus maybe a hash to avoid manipulation), then you should be able to re-create the same image at any point in the future, should it get requested again.

Comment: About the image: Yes, you are quite right. That way I don't need to store anything. Thanks for pointing it out. About the unique url, I guess theurl?brag=x, theurl?brag=y etc would work then. Maybe not the most beautiful solution but it's worth a shot. Thanks.